# Displaying empty controls in repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i need to display some text boxes, and have the ability for the user to "add another row"

i tried a datalist and a repeater, but it does not show anything at all, when the controls are blank.

```
<asp:DataList id="dlIso" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="vertical" >
<ItemTemplate>
test</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

so in this case "test" does now show at all..

what is the best way to get this accomplished?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to look at the `InsertItemTemplate`.</strike>

Sorry, that is for the new `ListView`.  I think last time I did this I used the `FooterTemplate`:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/datalist.aspx

I don't know if this is the way it should be done, but the footer stays regardless of the current page, so the insert controls are always visible.  It works well.  You can also simulate the command hyperlinks (edit, update, cancel, etc), but I can't remember off-hand how.

A good set of articles for the `ListView` can be found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061709-1.aspx

The linked page is also the one that discusses inserts, but I'd advise reading the lot as it starts from the beginning.

Comment: this still shows nothing.... do i need to bind it? what if all want to display is text....<asp:ListView ID="lstIso" runat="server">
<InsertItemTemplate>
insert new...</InsertItemTemplate></asp:ListView>

Comment: Believe so, it might need a bound list (even if empty) in order to work properly.  Off-hand I'm not sure, it's been a while since I last used one.

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide "Add Another Row" functionality for either a Repeater or a DataList, you will have to add another item to whatever datasource you're binding the control to, and call .DataBind().

If you're databinding to something that initially contains no records, you should use a control with an EmptyDataTemplate (GridView, ListView, or DetailsView).  For what you're doing, I would probably recommend the ListView.

Comment: i still can't get anything to display if the dataset is empty. for initial data entry...

Comment: Oh, the dataset is initially empty?  I missed that.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that until you don't bind your repeater to some `datasource` it will not show up any thing from the itemtemplate ... so you need to create some `datasource` against the text boxes and for every new row add an item to that `datasource` and re-bind the repeater ..
the number of item in your `datasource` is the number of rows you will get displayed on the front